# Bad request (400) при попытке подключения к серверу через сокеты

Tags: javascript, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, socket.io

Пытаюсь подключиться к серверу, но не получается (не знаю почему), в консоли ошибка

> GET http://localhost:1605/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ogtrm03 400 (Bad Request)

помогите исправить, пожалуйста (я сам не могу)

код клиента:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:1605');
socket.connect( "/", { secure: true, transports: [ "flashsocket","polling","websocket" ] } );
socket.on('connect', () => {
console.log('Подключено к серверу');
```

код сервера:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
cors: { origin: true, credentials: true}, allowEIO3: true 
});
// Обработчик подключения клиента
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('Новый клиент подключился!');
```

Comment: Но ошибка 400, а не 404...

Comment: Вы малость обрубили код серверной части, не могли бы пожалуйста прислать полностью (адреса и т.д. можно просто затереть если надо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу к сожалению оставлять комментарии

Проверьте включена ли на сервере поддержка протокола WS,
если выключена то соответственно включите его

Если не помогает, попробуйте для начала использовать `WebSocket` встроенный в JS
https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

Так же было бы уместно привести исходники серверной части приложения